# ScrollView Swipe Right not working XCode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I've a `scrollView` in which subviews are added and these subviews can be swiped top, right and left. But for some reason the swipe right does not seem to be working at all. I'm completely new to Objective-C, due to which i've been struggling real hard to make it work. I've a main view controller implementation with following code:
my `MainViewController.m` is

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _headerViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kHeaderId];
    _headerViewController.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:_headerViewController.view];

    _actionsListViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:kActionsListId];
    _actionsListViewController.delegate = self;
    [scrollView insertSubview:_actionsListViewController.view
                 belowSubview:_headerViewController.view];

    _agendasListViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:KAgendasListId];
    _agendasListViewController.delegate = self;
    [scrollView insertSubview:_agendasListViewController.view
                belowSubview:_headerViewController.view];    
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    [self positionSearchField:YES];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 2,
                                        scrollView.frame.size.height * 2);


    _headerViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,
                                                  scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                                  scrollView.frame.size.height);
    //action view will be displayed when swiped left
    _actionsListViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.frame.size.width, 0,
                                                       scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                                       scrollView.frame.size.height);
    //agenda view should have been displayed when swiped right
    _agendasListViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-scrollView.frame.size.width, 0,
                                                       scrollView.frame.size.width,
                                                       scrollView.frame.size.height); 

    _scrollViewBounds = scrollView.bounds;
}
```

and the `viewShouldScroll` function

```
- (void)viewShouldScroll:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection)direction {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x,
                              scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                              scrollView.frame.size.width,
                              scrollView.frame.size.height);    


    UIViewController *currentController = [self visibleViewController];

    switch (direction) {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp:
            frame.origin.y += scrollView.frame.size.height;
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
            //works fine and displays action view
            frame.origin.x += scrollView.frame.size.width;
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown:
            frame.origin.y -= scrollView.frame.size.height;
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
            if( currentController == _headerViewController ) {
                //does not work for agenda when swiped right
                NSLog(@"x position is %f@", frame.origin.x);
                frame.origin.x = -320; //hardcoded to check if this works, but doesnot
                NSLog(@"width is %f@", scrollView.frame.size.width); //gives -320
            }
            else {       
                //works fine when swiped from left to right to show main view       
                frame.origin.x -= scrollView.frame.size.width; //0
            }            
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }     
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```

Gesture recognizers have been added from storyboard for LEFT, RIGHT and TOP. As per the code, i've added agenda view with position of x as -320 in `CGRectMake` and on swipe right, i'm trying to make it visible by changing the `x` point of `frame.origin` but it does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have an example for swipe right on tabview work OK on ios 6 with the interaction like ios 7 -> it very cool. Refer here, easy to implement: https://github.com/runmad/RMSwipeTableViewCell

Comment: i'm not using TableView but ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it this way::

```
...
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * 3,
                                        scrollView.frame.size.height * 2);
...
```

I was using the width of `scrollView` as `scrollView.frame.size.width * 2`, which made the total width of scroll view double of `scrollView.frame.size.width`, but since i had 3 subviews in the main `scrollView`, i needed to do create `scrollView` with width 3 times the width of `scrollView` frame as `scrollView.frame.size.width * 3`